# how to Fly in fortnite?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I was playing zero build fornite mode on my PS5, I saw the guy flying all the time and was hitting infinite rocket launcher from the sky. It was not any small flying like hammer jump but he was constant in the air. he can also control his character in the air, it was last zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a glitch, I will try myself, I thought there must be a trick because I was totally new to Fornite. Hope Fornite will fix it soon.

[Youtube link of the glitch](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/AXAW4iAW1Rg)